# Moving files into specific directory using python get error file already exist

Tags: python, file

When I run  my code I get the same error like this :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-8d584fc326c3> in <module>
     16         filesToMove = gen_find("B"+str(o)+"_*",src)
     17         for name in filesToMove:
---> 18             shutil.move(name, dst)
Error: Destination path 'Dataset/300_train/1\B1_1.jpg' already exists
```

Can anyone help me to check my code here?:

please give some explaination

```
import os
import shutil
import fnmatch

def gen_find(filepat,top):
    for path, dirlist, filelist in os.walk(top):
        for name in fnmatch.filter(filelist,filepat):
            yield os.path.join(path,name)

ranges = list(range(1,51))
for o in ranges:
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        src = 'Dataset/300_train' # input
        dst = 'Dataset/300_train/'+str(o) # desired     location

        filesToMove = gen_find("B"+str(o)+"_*",src)
        for name in filesToMove:
            shutil.move(name, dst)
```

I want to skip to copy the file if there's already exists

Comment: Well you probably ran the code a few times so some of the files really do exist. If you want help you have to tell us what to do if there's already a file there. Should the copy be skipped? Should the new file overwrite the old one? Should the program keep both but rename them?

Comment: I want to skip it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you meantioned in your comment, if you want to skip the file if it's already there, it's really quite simple with a `try... except` block. You need to replace this part of your code

```
for name in filesToMove:
    shutil.move(name, dst)
```

with this:

```
for name in filesToMove:
    try:
        shutil.move(name, dst)
    except shutil.Error:
        pass
```

Comment: Bare `except ` clauses are dangerous and can hide unrelated problems and make debugging difficult. Suggest you use `except OSError:` instead.

Comment: @martineau You are correct, I edited to be more specific